# Linear Independence of vectors in relation to the $t$ parameter

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

> Considering the following vectors $u,v,w\in R^5$
>
> $u = (0,1,1,-1,1/2)$ $v = (t,1,1,0,1)$ $w = (1,3,3,-2,-2)$
>
> Then, they are linearly independent:
>
> **a**) for each value of $t$ **b**) if and only if $t=0$ **c**) if $t=1$ **d**) if and only if $t\neq 1$

I think the best way to solve the exercise, is to find a combination of elements that is equal to the zero vector. So I go on in this way:

$\alpha(0,1,1,-1,1/2)+\beta(t,1,1,0,1)+\gamma(1,3,3,-2,-2) = (0,0,0,0,0)$

finding ways for which $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are equal to $0$, but I cannot get the result through the calculations. Any advices?

Comment: Just use these as column vectors in a matrix and row reduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vectors are linearly independent if and only if the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & t & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 3 \\
1 & 1 & 3 \\
-1 & 0 & -2 \\
1/2 & 1 & -2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
has rank $3$.

We can do Gaussian elimination: swap the first and second row and eliminate in the first column, getting
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 3 \\
0 & t & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1/2 & -7/2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now swap the second and fourth column; then eliminate in the second column:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1-t \\
0 & 0 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then you have the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! In this way the calculations are extremely easier. But, why the rank must be exactly $3$?

Comment: @GabrieleSalvatori If it is not $3$, the vectors are linearly dependent. In this case the rank is $3$ independently of $t$. Had the $(5.3)$ place coefficient in the final matrix been $0$, the rank would be $3$ for $1-t\ne0$ and $2$ for $1-t=0$.